# How to pass IronMQ Token Through Query String

Tags: java, jsp, jms, token, ironmq

I am trying to retrieve the Messages from IronMQ,
For that i am sending one request, I also include my ProjectID and Token, Still i am getting a response of Token is required. Can you please help??
Thanks in Advance:

Here is my code :

```
<form id="myform" action="https://mq-aws-us-east-1-2.iron.io/3/projects/575526342343c707/queues/testQueue1/messages?oAuth=3b33k3i4pf689wpCvQZ9CO method="get">
<a onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();">Send Request to IronMQ</a>

</form>
```

The response is :

```
{"msg":"Token required for authentication"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't post your token on Stackoverflow.

Second, it should be "oauth", all lowercase I believe.

Third, you didn't close the quotes on the action parameter.

Comment: What project id and token i pass was dummy. The closing quotes in the action parameter was the actual problem. Thanks for a feed back